# Función cuando un cronómetro llega a un tiempo

Tags: java, android, timer

tengo una código de cronometro tal que así:

```
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (encendido == false){
                encendido = true;
                boton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_grey600_24dp);

                if (mLastStopTime == 0){
                    simpleChronometer.setBase( SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() );
                } else {
                    long intervalOnPause = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastStopTime);
                    simpleChronometer.setBase(simpleChronometer.getBase() + intervalOnPause);
                }

                simpleChronometer.start();
            } else if (encendido == true){
                encendido = false;
                boton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_grey600_24dp);
                simpleChronometer.stop();

                mLastStopTime = (int) SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            }

        }
    });
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el cronometro llegue a 10 minutos se pare, o que se pause o cualquier función otra función.

Comment: Hola Victor. y por qué tu codigo no hace lo que pides? Te arroja errores o no funciona como esperas?

Comment: Tengo hecho un cronometro que funciona perfectamente pero no encuentro la manera de hacer que cuando llegue a X tiempo haga una función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes implementar la interfaz [**Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener.html), por medio del método `onChronometerTick()`,  realizas la comparación del tiempo transcurrido, si es igual simplemente detienes el cronometro.

```
  simpleChronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                        if( chronometer.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("10:00")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Detiene chronometer @ 10 minutos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //Detiene cronometro.
                            simpleChronometer.stop();
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! la verdad es que había estado toqueteando el método onChronometerTick() pero no había sido capaz de hacerlo funcionar correctamente. Esto de empezar android por mi cuenta me va gustando cada vez más gracias a la comunidad.

Comment: Excelente Victor, en un futuro tu puedes compartir tu conocimiento con otros usuarios, saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ